# Modify excel appearance with c# in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-2007

I have a winform application that contains an excel viewer in one of its forms.It lets user
to open and modify excel files. but i want to avoid users to create any new sheets,

so i need to know :

**How can i get rid of the last tab of workbook tabs that allows user to add new sheet?**

[image]

**Edit :**

I have found the following code to unvisible the button in the above image:

```
ExcelViewer1.Application.CommandBars["Workbook tabs"].Controls["Sheet List"].Visible = false;
```

But it thrown a COMException : "**Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a com component**".

The same command works for other commandbars like *Ply*, *Cell*

Comment: You are using Excel class?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 1):

We can disable the functionality of sheet insert tab by doing something like this

```
workbook.Protect(Type.Missing, true, true);
```

also you could take a look at the following link [Check this link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/377839-disable-insert-worksheet-feature.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 Thanks Kyle, but i want to hide that Tab so the user could not see it at all.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you may try this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/cc442817.aspx) to add control to your Workbook then

add a sheet using this piece of code

```
Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(
missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I visited your suggested link but it is about Console.WriteLine Method!?

Comment: This is nothing to do with the question

Comment: He does not want to add a sheet to the workbook.. this still has nothing to do with the question